# Mathematical shortcut to determine if a number is a integer

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, integers, square-numbers

Well, let's say I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. This function is a polynomial of degree three under a square root sign, which means that is in the form of:

$$f(x):=\sqrt{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d}\tag1$$

Where $a,b,c$ and $d$ are integer coefficients (so they can be positive, negative or equal to zero) and $x\ge2$ and $x\in\mathbb{N}$.

Is there a (fast) way to determine for what $x$ we get: $f(x)\in\mathbb{N}$?

---

**My work**

I ran a Mathematica search, using specific values for $a,b,c$ and $d$. To be more specific I set $a=300,b=90,c=-210$ and $d=144$.

The code I used is as follows:

```
ParallelTable[If[IntegerQ@Sqrt[6*(24+5*x*(1+x)*(10*x-7))],x,Nothing],{x,2,10^9}]
```

But it will take way to long in order to finish this computation.

> Is there a clever mathematical 'trick' that can be used to eliminate the number of values to check?

Comment: Mh, you didn't say that $x$ must be integer, so you are essentially asking for the real roots of $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d-n^2=0$ it seems.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I edited my question. Because $x$ is indeed an integer

Comment: $y^2=$ a cubic in $x$ is generally what's called an *elliptic curve*. Occasionally there are elementary ways to find all the integer solutions, but usually more advanced methods must be used. A websearch will bring up lots of helpful material.

Comment: @GerryMyerson is there a general form of the curves that can be solved elementary?

Comment: I think those are few & far between. Have you done a websearch for "elliptic curves" yet?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes I did, but the math is very complicated so I can not see where to start.

Comment: Unfortunately, the math of elliptic curves is very complicated. Fermat was able to handle a few examples of the form $y^2=x^3+k$ by elementary means. Nowadays that general form is known as the Mordell equation. Maybe a search for Fermat Mordell will turn something up.

Comment: You may find https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142220/fermats-proof-for-x3-y2-2 informative, although it mostly talks about how an elementary method *doesn't* work.

Comment: I think you'll enjoy https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf

Comment: Have you had a look at that last link I left?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes but I didn't see how it can help me solving my question

Comment: Well, as I wrote, finding all the integer solutions to an equation of the form $y^2=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ can get you into very deep mathematical waters very quickly. You can do a degree in math at a good college and never get to see the math you need to solve such equations. All I can suggest is that you keep searching, maybe you'll come across something helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equation of the form $y^2 = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ is known as an **elliptic curve**. The integer solutions to $y^2 = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$ are known as **integral points** of $y^2 = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, or simply solutions of the diophantine equation $y^2 = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$. These are usually solved using Skolem's $p$-adic method ([here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01472228) and [here](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/box/bachelorscriptie_josha_box_eindversie.pdf)), or one can use 3 other methods described in the article by Don Zagier [here](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.2307/2007900/fulltext.pdf), two using Pell equations and one using group theory.